# Ruby interpolation can't be read inside raw method in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a `link_to` line of code that will have a dynamic sprites/icons.

The link image must be dynamic based on `provider` name and it must have css sprites so I used `raw` to design it.

```
= link_to raw('<div class="#{provider.name}_sprites">&nbsp;</div>'), directory_user_path(provider_id: provider.id, creator: creator.id), remote: true
```

Actually, sprites are working if class name is static but upon checking via Gchrome's inspect element... the class name becomes

`#{provider.name}_sprites`

Meaning: the variable wasn't read as a valid ruby variables.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation only works inside double quoted strings, not single quoted ones. Use double quotes, and escape you inner double quotes or replace them with single ones:

```
"<div class='#{provider.name}_sprites'>&nbsp;</div>"
```

This has nothing to do with the `raw` method.

Comment: Woah didn't realize that. Thanks a lot. Another thing to remember.

Comment: I'll accept after 10 minutes as per SOverflow rules. Thanks @thilo